# Notificaciones distorsionadas al tener mi app abierta KOTLIN-PHP mediante CLOUD MESSAGING FIREBASE

Tags: php, android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-messaging

Estoy con una app móvil hecha con Kotlin en la cual mando notificaciones mediante un back de PHP, cuando las notificaciones se mandan y la app no ​​está abierta sale todo bien, pero cuando mando una notificación y la app está abierta sale distorsionada y no se puede ver lo que dice la notificación. A lo que estuve viendo debe ser problema del front en Kotlin que recibe los parámetros de la notificación. Otro problema que hay es que envío el parámetro de icono pero no me lo respeta y se pone el icono por defecto e igual el color, pero de igual manera solo pasa cuando la app está abierta, cuando está cerrada si respeta esos parámetros.

Este es el código de kotlin que recibe los parámetros de la notificación:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private fun generateNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        var pendingIntent : PendingIntent

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        }else{
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        }

        var  builder : NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tv)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        builder = builder.setContent(getRemoteView(title, message))

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build())
    }

    @SuppressLint
    private fun getRemoteView(title: String, message: String) : RemoteViews {
        val remoteView = RemoteViews("com.example.fcmpushnotifications", R.layout.notification)
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title)
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message)
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_tv)

        return remoteView
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        if (message.notification != null){
            generateNotification(message.notification!!.title!!, message.notification!!.body!!)
        }
    }

}
```

Y este es el back en PHP que manda los parámetros:

```
$notification = array('title' => $titulo,
                              'subtitle' => $subtitulo,
                              'body' => $msg,
                              'icon' => 'ic_myicon',
                              'color' => 'BLACK'
                              //'sound' => 'mySound'
                        );
        
$fields = array('registration_ids'=>$tokens_dispositivos, 'notification'=>$notification);     
$payload = json_encode($fields); 
echo $payload;        
// Abrir la sesión       
$ch = curl_init();      
// Definir la URL a la que se le hará el post    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fcmUrl);       
// Indicar el tipo de petición: POST    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER );        
// Definir cada uno de los parámetros        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);       
$result = curl_exec($ch);       
//Cerrar la sesión       
curl_close($ch);       
echo $result;
```

A continuación de cómo salen las notificaciones con la app abierta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver al desplegarse la notificación se interponen dos iconos, y al bajar la barra de notificaciones no se muestra el icono, titulo ni mensaje que debería mostrarse, solo se muestra el icono por defecto.

A continuación de cómo salen las notificaciones con la app cerrada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, respeta todos los parámetros enviados por el backend de PHP, mostrando icono, color de icono, titulo y mensaje correcto.

Comment: Podrías agregar una imagen de como se muestra "distorsionada" la notificación.

Comment: Listo, ya agregué las imágenes de cómo sale con la app cerrada y con la app abierta